# Simple PHP contact form on Amazon Web Services EC2

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp

I'm looking for a simple solution to get a simple PHP contact form to work on a Amazon EC2 LAMP stack. It seems like Amazon don't give you this functionality (mail()) and having searched around, the alternatives are far too excessive.

**Option 1 -**
Configure Amazon SES with PostFix
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-app.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html

**Option 2 -**
Set up sendmail on the server. I'm fairly new to setting up linux servers and reading into this it's wanting me to configure and set up smtp servers which is way beyond me. Not entirely sure this would solve my problem either.

Can anyone point me towards any alternative options or point me towards strong documentation to guide me through?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think it's better to ask them here to allow you to use mail() function in PHP.

https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

Answer (score 0):

Instructions mentioned in the following link can be followed. In this method installing postfix, sendmail or any other mail server is not required.

It uses the PHPMailer class to send email through Amazon SES using the SMTP interface.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-php.html

It took me a whole day to reach this simpler solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66457055/13150101