# Cannot Send Email from EC2

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting

I have a registration form on my website which sends an email when submitted. Initially, I had my domain and hosting from GoDaddy. Recently I changed my hosting provider to AWS. Now, my website is not able to send emails.What is likely to be problem, it worked fine with GoDaddy? Also GoDaddy's email service was extremely slow. Do I need to use a separate email service e.g. Gmail (I need an email which is: suppport@mywebsite.com).

Comment: How are you trying to send emails from aws?

Comment: @Dagon I have written code using PHP and using its mail() function. Though I changed my host provider nothing updated in code. May be previously mail() was using Godaddy free email service.

Comment: On aws you have to install your own mail server and get them to white list it or use SES

Comment: @Dagon What do you really mean of "install your own mail server" , is it buying some kind of service from external entity like Gmail or Microsoft and configuring it ? Can you point me to some link which explain it in details. I feel  some kind of alienated for this email stuff.

Comment: @Dagon Running server is not equal to running email service. Email service needed extra configuration which is not directly understandable to new user of it. If it was related to programming which is not depends on other entity then I could have done it already.

Comment: I would not call AWS "new user" frendly

Comment: I don't think he's wrong. Perhaps this [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858457/send-mail-using-amazon-ec2-instance) helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

Reading through the comments, I see you are using PHP mail() function - by default this uses Port 25 to send emails and on Public Cloud providers such as AWS and GCP these are blocked by default.

You have three options:

- You can request to remove the Port 25 block on your AWS instance: https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request
- You can use Amazon SES to give you an SMTP Endpoint to send your mail: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html
- You can use a third-party service such as SendGrid which allows you to send emails over Port 2525 instead which will resolve your issues.